# What setup do you need for Python Visualizations in Power BI? Any particular matplotlib package versions or system settings?

Tags: python, powerbi

I keep getting the error `TypeError: from_bounds() takes 4 positional arguments but 6 were given` when trying to insert a Python Visualization in Power BI.
Though it seems that Matplotlib is the problem here, I don't know if that is the root cause.

**My system:**

```
Windows 7, 64 bit
Power BI august 2018
Python 3.6.6.0
Matplotlib 2.2.2
Pandas 0.23.4
```

I can't be 100% sure that this is in fact a version problem, but I can't think of anything else because I'm using the same dataset that was successfully used in the post [What is the best data format for a time series in a Python Visualization in Power BI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761926/what-is-the-best-data-format-and-setup-for-a-time-series-in-a-python-visualizati).

**Data:**

```
Date,Value
2017-01-12,1
2017-01-13,4
2017-01-14,2
2017-01-15,4
2017-01-16,2
2017-01-17,2
2017-01-18,2
2017-01-19,5
2017-01-20,5
2017-01-21,5
2017-01-22,5
2017-01-23,6
2017-01-24,3
2017-01-25,6
2017-01-26,6
2017-01-27,5
2017-01-28,8
2017-01-29,4
2017-01-30,2
```

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(dataset['Date'], dataset['Value'])
plt.show()
```

**Error message screenshot:**

[image]

**Edit 1 - The complete error message:**

> Feedback Type: Frown (Error)
>
> Timestamp: 2018-08-15T09:58:44.0322850Z
>
> Local Time: 2018-08-15T11:58:44.0322850+02:00
>
> Session ID: 85df81af-81bb-4f82-a7f4-062b315cb370
>
> Release: August, 2018
>
> Product Version:
>   2.61.5192.601 (18.08) (x64)
>
> Error Message: Python script error. Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 6, in 
>       matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize=(3,75,3,52777777777778))   File "C:\Users\userinfo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
>   line 548, in figure
>       **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\userinfo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py",
>   line 160, in new_figure_manager
>       fig = fig_cls(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\userinfo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
>   line 361, in **init**
>       self.bbox_inches = Bbox.from_bounds(0, 0, *figsize) TypeError: from_bounds() takes 4 positional arguments but 6 were given
>
> OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (x64 nb-NO)
>
> CLR Version:
>   4.7 or later [Release Number = 461310]
>
> Peak Virtual Memory:
>   4.16 GB
>
> Private Memory: 398 MB
>
> Peak Working Set: 532 MB
>
> IE Version:
>   11.0.9600.19035
>
> User ID: IDnumber
>
> Workbook Package Info: 1* - nb-NO, Query Groups: 0, fastCombine:
>   Enabled, runBackgroundAnalysis: True.
>
> Telemetry Enabled: True
>
> Model Default Mode: Import
>
> Snapshot Trace Logs: C:\Users\userinfo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power
>   BI Desktop\FrownSnapShot1416353677.zip
>
> Performance Trace Logs:
>   C:\Users\userinfo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI
>   Desktop\PerformanceTraces.zip
>
> Enabled Preview Features: PBI_PythonSupportEnabled
>
> Disabled Preview Features: PBI_shapeMapVisualEnabled PBI_newFromWeb
>   PBI_SpanishLinguisticsEnabled CustomConnectors PBI_variationUIChange
>   PBI_canvasTooltips PBI_showIncrementalRefreshPolicy
>   PBI_compositeModels PBI_DB2DQ
>
> Disabled DirectQuery Options: PBI_DirectQuery_Unrestricted
>   TreatHanaAsRelationalSource
>
> Cloud: GlobalCloud
>
> DPI Scale: 100%
>
> Supported Services: Power BI
>
> Formulas:
>
> section Section1;
>
> shared timeseries = let
>       Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\data\timeseries.csv"),[Delimiter=",",
>   Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
>       #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
>       #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Date", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}) in
>       #"Changed Type";

Comment: Can you `Copy Details` and post the full error?

Comment: I added it just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK now it's obvious where the error comes from.

In the line (which Power BI generates on the fly):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize=(5,87473572938689,6,87403100775194))
```

It grabs the dimensions in your locale (which in this case use ',' as decimal point) and passes it to `figsize`.

While [figsize](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) accepts a tuple of (width, height) in inches as input, `5,87473572938689,6,87403100775194` is treated as 4 arguments, instead of 2, which causes the error.

---

So to work around this, you can either explicitly pass `figsize` (using values with `.` as decimal point) to `plt.figure`, i.e.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5.874,6.874))
plt.plot(dataset['Date'], dataset['Value'])
plt.show()
```

Or change the locale in Power BI to one which use `.` as decimal points instead of `,`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with different datasets with integers only and no dates, but I still got the same problem. That's why I thought that It could not be caused by the decimal symbol. I did not know that that could cause problems like this as well.

Comment: I tried explicitly passing two integers to figsize, but I'm still getting the same error. So it seems changing the locale is the only solution here. I can write that up as a new question if you prefer that.

Comment: So it's still the same error after you pass two integers to figsize?